# HP Fortify. Issues while handling very large fpr reports on fortify server

Tags: sonarqube, fortify

We have this huge source-code base. We scan it using HP SCA and create a fpr file ( size app 620 MB). Then we upload it to our fortify server using "fortifyclient" command.

After uploading, if i log into the fortify server and go into details of that project, i see that the artifact is in "processing" stage. It remains in processing stage even after few days. There is no way provided on the dashboard using which i can stop /kill/delete it.

Ques 1: Why is it taking so long to process ( We have 1 successfully processed fpr report that took 6 days ). What can we do to make it faster?

Ques 2: If i want to delete a artifact while it in in processing stage, how to do that?

Machine Info:
6 CPUs (Intel(R) Xeon(R) 3.07GHz )
RAM 36 gig

Thanks,

Addition:
We had 1 report that was successfully processed earlier in the month for the same codebase. FPR file for that was of also of similar size (610 MB ) . I can see the issue count for that report. Here it is:

EDIT:

Fortify Version:  Fortify Static Code Analyzer 6.02.0014

HP Fortify Software Security Center Version 4.02.0014

Total issues: 157000

Total issues Audited: 0.0%

Critical issues: 4306

High:   151200

Low:  1640

medium:  100

Comment: The first thing that you need to do is verify that you are running the latest version of Fortify (4.21).  The second thing you need to do is identify issue counts per category.  It sounds like you may have a certain category that is producing abnormally high issue counts.  You can do that by opening it in Audit Workbench.  Post those here and perhaps we can come up with a solution.

Comment: Added few more details above. Thanks

Comment: 157k issues is a lot of issues.  Please post the information requested:

Fortify Version: `{your version}`
Issues in Category [X]: `{count}`
Issues in Category [Y]: `{count}`
Issues in Category [Z]: `{count}`

Comment: Added above in the description.

Comment: Sorry, when I say Categry, I mean like `SQL Injection` or `Cross Site Scripting` or `Null Dereference`.  Also 4.02 had a few issues with excessive issue counts in a few categories.  Please also ensure that you are using the latest rulepacks.

Comment: Following 2 types of issues make bulk ( About 85% ) of the total issues.  1)    Cross-Site Scripting Persistent    2)Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected and within these 2 only about 10% are critical

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Java?  Web?  Javascript?  Do you use 3rd party javascript libs?  With a large code base, do you have multiple copies of 3rd party libs?  Fortify has issues with some 3rd party javascript libs especially if multiple copies are present.  Can you give a count of XSS errors per file (fake file names like A, B, C)?  File A: [Count], File B: [Count], etc.

Comment: FILE1.java [1034 ( all pointing to 4 diff line numbers)]  ,   FILE2.java [521 all on same line number ] , FILE3.java [64 all on same line number ]   and so on.  Does this mean the same issue is being reported multiple times?  if so, is it the problem with the FPR report or the Fortify server analyzing this report?

Comment: Yes, it does mean the issue is being reported multiple times.  This is most likely an issue with SourceAnalyzer.  My recommendation would be to upgrade to the latest (4.21) and re-run the scan.  Two other options for `DIAGNOSTIC PURPOSES ONLY` would be to A) exclude the affected files (using the -exclude argument for sourceanalyzer) or B) to alter the files in question so that Fortify does not catch them.

Comment: Another thing to look at are warnings and errors.  These are on the Summary information for the FPR.  You can look at this data in Audit Workbench.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. I will work on these things and update

Comment: I just wanted to follow up with you on this issue.  Were you able to resolve the high issue counts?  Also 4.30 was just released and is supposed to have great improvements in SCA and SSC.

Comment: Partially.  Trying to create a smaller report. But the report without source code wont work for us. Another thing that i wanted to ask is about where can i find some details about default tables in the fortify DB? Suppose i want to remove reports manually. what tables do need to modify?

Answer (score 1):

That's a large FPR file, so it will need time to process. SSC is basically unzipping a huge ZIP file (that's what an FPR file is) and then transferring the data into the database. Here are a few things to check:

- Check the amount of memory allotted for SSC. You may need to pass up to 16Gb of memory as the Xmx value to handlean FPR that size. Maybe more. The easiest way to tell would be to upload the FPR and then watch the java process that your app server uses. See how long it takes to reach the maximum amount of memory.
- Make sure the database is configured for performance. Having the database on a separate server with the data files on another hard drive can significantly speed of processing.
- As a last resort, you could also try making the FPR smaller. You can turn off the source rendering so that source code is not bundled with the FPR file. You can do this with this command:

  sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -disable-source-bundling
  -fvdl-no-snippets -scan -f mySourcelessResults.fpr

As far as deleting an in progress upload, I think you have to let it finish. With some tuning, you should be able to get the processing time down.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We will try it with higher memory allocated to SSC. In the meantime can you please suggest which specific database configuration should we change to get better performance. Right now i am using database installed on the same machine with default configurations

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: We are using Oracle DB 11.

Comment: @Eric, I would not turn off the source rendering as it makes auditing harder.  While offering tuning tips is helpful, it would be better to get to the root cause of the large FPR.

Comment: @ James It makes auditing harder, but you can attach the source back to the FPR when opening it in one of the client tools. That's the reason why I said it's a last resort. From what I'm hearing, the cause of the large FPR is a large code base. To make the FPR smaller you either have to cut the source code out, or you have to cut down on the analysis. I would much rather have to view issues in AWB using local source code than decrease the level of analysis.

@pun This guide may help:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573.pdf